# Load Balancing with Memory and Disk

Tags: performance, memory, load, load-balancing, disk

I've found load balancers such as NGINX but those seem to work only by keeping in mind CPU usage and traffic. How would I load balance with respect to other variables such as the amount of disk available at each node, or the amount of memory available?

Would I have to write my own request handling service in order to take advantage of those variables when deciding which node to send the request to?

Thank you for helping with my first question.

Comment: You probably want to post this question on "Super User" section of stack exchange. Or "Server Fault"

Comment: thank you, is there a way for me to move my question or do i have to delete and reask?

Comment: I don't know :-) most likely you will need to delete / reask. I want to know the answer too so will have to track you again. I guess you can also leave it as it is and just copy/paste the hyperlink to question on another stack.

Comment: asked again here http://serverfault.com/questions/771899/how-to-load-balance-with-respect-to-memory-disk-usage-and-other-attributes thank you for the suggestion